# Perl and Environment Variables

Tags: perl

Some of the environment variables which we use in Unix are as below (just an example):

```
VAR1=variable1
VAR2=variable2
VAR3=variable3
# and so on
```

Now, I have a perl script (let's call it `test.pl)` which reads a tab delimited text file (let's call it `test.txt`) and pushes the contents of it columnwise in separate arays. The first column of `test.txt` contains the following information for example (the strings in first column are delimited by `/` but I do not know how may `/` a string would contain and at what position the environment variable would appear):

```
$VAR1/$VAR2/$VAR3
$VAR3/some_string/SOME_OTHER_STRING/and_so_on/$VAR2
$VAR2/$VAR1/some_string/some_string_2/some_string_3/some_string_n/$VAR2
```

The extract of the script is as below:

```
use strict;
my $input0 = shift or die "must provide test.txt as the argument 0\n";
open(IN0,"<",$input0) || die "Cannot open $input0 for reading: $!";
my @first_column;
while (<IN0>)
{
   chomp;
   my @cols = split(/\t/);
   my $first_col = `eval $cols[0]`; #### but this does not work
   # here goes the push stmt to populate the array
   ### more code here
}
close(IN0);
```

Question: How can I access environment variables in such a situation so that the array is populated as below:

```
$first_column[0] = variable1/vraible2/variable3
$first_column[1] = variable3/some_string/SOME_OTHER_STRING/and_so_on/variable2
$first_column[2] = variable2/variable1/some_string/some_string_2/some_string_3/some_string_n/variable2
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, please clarify.....

Comment: I have shown the sample input and I have shown the desired result. What else should I add now?

Comment: Do you also allow for normal shell expansions of words like ${VAR1:-foo} or complex expansions (ie bashisms) like ${VAR1//foo/bar}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for a way to process configuration files. I like [Config::Std](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Config::Std) for that purpose although there are many others on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/).

---

Here is a way of processing just the contents of `$cols[0]` to show in an explicit way what you need to do with it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

# You should not type this. I am assuming the
# environment variables are defined in the environment.
# They are here for testing.
@ENV{qw(VAR1 VAR2 VAR3)} = qw(variable1 variable2 variable3);

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    last unless $line =~ /\S/;
    chomp $line;
    my @components = split qr{/}, $line;
    for my $c ( @components ) {
        if ( my ($var) = $c =~ m{^\$(\w+)\z} ) {
            if ( exists $ENV{$var} ) {
                $c = $ENV{$var};
            }
        }
    }
    print join('/', @components), "\n";
}

__DATA__
$VAR1/$VAR2/$VAR3
$VAR3/some_string/SOME_OTHER_STRING/and_so_on/$VAR2
$VAR2/$VAR1/some_string/some_string_2/some_string_3/some_string_n/$VAR2
```

Instead of the `split`/`join`, you can use `s///` to replace patterns that look like variables with the corresponding values in `%ENV`. For illustration, I put a second column in the `__DATA__` section which is supposed to stand for a description of the path, and turned each line in to a hashref. Note, I factored out the actual substitution to `eval_path` so you can try alternatives without messing with the main loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

# You should not type this. I am assuming the
# environment variables are defined in the environment.
# They are here for testing.
@ENV{qw(VAR1 VAR2 VAR3)} = qw(variable1 variable2 variable3);

my @config;
while ( my $config = <DATA> ) {
    last unless $config =~ /\S/;
    chomp $config;
    my @cols = split /\t/, $config;
    $cols[0] = eval_path( $cols[0] );
    push @config, { $cols[1] => $cols[0] };
}

use YAML;
print Dump \@config;

sub eval_path {
    my ($path) = @_;
    $path =~ s{\$(\w+)}{ exists $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : $1 }ge;
    return $path;
}

__DATA__
$VAR1/$VAR2/$VAR3   Home sweet home
$VAR3/some_string/SOME_OTHER_STRING/and_so_on/$VAR2 Man oh man
$VAR2/$VAR1/some_string/some_string_2/some_string_3/some_string_n/$VAR2 Can't think of any other witty remarks ;-)
```

Output:

```
---
- Home sweet home: variable1/variable2/variable3
- Man oh man: variable3/some_string/SOME_OTHER_STRING/and_so_on/variable2
- Can't think of any other witty remarks ;-): variable2/variable1/some_string/some_string_2/some_string_3/some_string_n/variable2
```

Comment: I agree, just use a Config module rather than reinventing the wheel... IMHO the difference between a beginner programmer and an intermediate programmer is the intermediate programmer starts to have the mindset *"there is **no way** my problem has never been encountered by someone else before... I bet there is a library that already solves this for me."* The beginner just forges ahead thinking they are in uncharted territory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow for full shell expansions, one option to use the shell to do the expansion for you, perhaps via echo:

```
$ cat input
$FOO
bar
${FOO//cat/dog}
$ FOO=cat perl -wpe '$_ = qx"echo $_"' input
cat
bar
dog
```

If you cannot trust the contents of the environment variable, this introduces a security risk, as invoking qx on a string may cause the shell to invoke commands embedded in the string.  As a result, this scriptlet will not run under taint mode (-T).

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to do this:

```
my @cols = map { s/(\$(\w+))/ $ENV{$2} || $1 /ge; $_ } split /\t/;
```

What you would do here is after you split them you would take each sequence of `'$'` followed by *word* characters and check to see if there was an environment variable for the word portion of it, otherwise leave it as is.

- The `e` switch on a substitution allows you to execute code for the replacement value.
- If you expect a `'0'` for any environment variable value, it's better off to do a *defined or*, that came in with 5.10.

  ```
  my @cols = map { s|(\$(\w+))| $ENV{$2} // $1 |ge; $_ } split /\t/;
  ```

(Ignore the markup. `//` is a defined-or, not a C-comment)

Answer (score 0):

Perl keeps its environment variables in [`%ENV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25ENV), in your case you can change your code like so:

```
my $first_col = $ENV[$cols[0]];
```

Comment: I think this would not work because exact contains of $cols[0] are not available in %ENV. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @sachin: Yes, there might be a more functional and more elegant solution using a regex, but please tell us what the 'exact contents' would be. Why wouldn't they be available in `%ENV`?

Comment: @MvanGeest `%ENV` would  have `$ENV{VAR1}` etc. Not `$ENV{$VAR1/$VAR2/$VAR3}`.